# CFBundleIconFiles Key is not Showing Up in XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm having trouble adding multiple icon files to my application's info.plist file. I've read the docs on Apple's site, and I've read many of the articles here on StackOverflow, but something isn't quite right.

When I open my info.plist file and click the "+" button next to the entry for "Icon File", I make an attempt to add an entry for "Icon files" (notice the added "s"). This entry does not come up in the dropdown list, however. And when I switch the view to "Show Raw Keys/Values", only the CFBundleIconFile shows up. The necessary CFBundleIconFiles (again, notice the "s") does not show up in my dropdown list.

Is there a setting in XCode I need to set to get these new values to show up? I'm running 3.2.6 with SDK 4.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I follow correctly, you're having issues with enabling multiple icon files and their respective resolutions? Apart from setting the main one inside your .plist (as you're using XC3, whereas XC4's interface allows for retina and non-retina selections built in) the others simply need to be in the same place as your main Icon.png file.

This might further help you:

[iPhone icon size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195240/iphone-icon-size)